# How to replace parts of a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, typescript

I have a URL that I want to replace parts of, depending on the call I'm making.

For example, my URL is of the form

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/server/32/users/255667753/images/233.jpg"
```

I want to make calls to different URLs of the same form but with only the numbers changed. Currently, I am doing it like this

```
var urlPart1 = "http://www.example.com/server/"
var urlPart2 = "/users/";
var urlPart3 = "/images/";
var urlPart4 = ".jpg";

var sendRequestTo = urlPart1 + 32 + urlPart2 + 255667753 + urlPart3 + 233 + urlPart4.
```

However, is there a better way, like there is in Java?

Comment: how exactly does java do it? how do you want the code to look?

Comment: I guess he means `String.format()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TypeScript is more on the side of object oriented programming, we need to extend interface. We need to extend the String interface and then we need to supply an implementation:

```
interface String {
    format(...replacements: string[]): string;
}

if (!String.prototype.format) {
  String.prototype.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
      return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
        ? args[number]
        : match
      ;
    });
  };
}
```

And you can user anywhere this way:

```
var myStr = 'This is an {0} for {0} purposes: {1}';

alert(myStr.format('example', 'end'));
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var regexp = /\{(\d+)\}/g, values = arguments;
    return this.replace(regexp, function(match, index) {
      return values[index];
    });
  };

var server = "http://www.example.com";
console.log("{0} is {1}".format("a", "b"));
console.log("{3}/server/{0}/users/{1}/images/{2}.jpg".format(32, 255667753, 233, server));
```

This approach is more like c# though which allows you to put the arguments in any order.

Comment: so there is nothing built in that does this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare this function globally somewhere

String.prototype.format = function (args) {
    var newStr = this;
    for (var key in args) {
        newStr = newStr.replace('{' + key + '}', args[key]);
    }
    return newStr;
}

// This is generic url that will be formatted on the fly with dynamic numbers
var url = "http://www.example.com/server/{serverNo}/users/{userNo}/images/{imgNo}.jpg"

// call it with your dynamic numbers
url = url.format({serverNo:230948,userNo:123897,imgNo:1239378});

And finally your url will become 
"http://www.example.com/server/230948/users/123897/images/1239378.jpg"

Happy coding.. :)
```

Comment: Would it be the same answer in Typescript?

Comment: The answer to every "How do I accomplish X runtime task in TypeScript" question is always the same as the answer to the "How do I accomplish X runtime task in JavaScript" question

Comment: I added answer to your question below.